# Is there a way to style a TextView to lowercase all of its letters?

Tags: java, android, textview, lowercase

`nameTextview.setAllCaps(true);` by this we can set all text to Uppercase letter,
How I can set Lowercase ?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView nameTextview;
private Button button1;
private Button button2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1=findViewById(R.id.capsonID);
    button2=findViewById(R.id.capsoffID);
    nameTextview = findViewById(R.id.textview1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            nameTextview.setAllCaps(true);
        }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            nameTextview.  // ???????????? What should I do here ?
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Convert your text String to lower case and then set it to your `TextView` instead.

Comment: add ontextchanged listener, where you change text to lowercase

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.. what ever your string to want to set textview. the String class provide method for lower and upper letter.

```
tv.setText(strings.toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getText() method in this TextView and save the text into a String object. And you can use toLowerCase() method to convert the string into all lowercase then use setText() method to set the modified String to that TextView
Remember to set the setAllCaps() to false

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, you can use this to change to lowercase:

```
    nameTextview.setText.nameTextview.getText().toString().toLowerCase());
```

However, if you are looking for something like `setAllCaps` does, that is, change the text to lowercase without modifying the original text, then, you should use a transformation method.

Indeed, `setAllCaps(true)`, change string to Uppercase:

```
'Hello, This Is a Test' => 'HELLO, THIS IS A TEST'
```

But if you set setAllCaps(false) the text change like this

```
'HELLO, THIS IS A TEST' => 'Hello, This Is a Test'
```

The original text is recovered as it was entered.

To accomplish this to Lowercase you should create a class like this:

```
public class AllLowTransformationMethod implements TransformationMethod {
    private Locale mLocale;

    public AllLowTransformationMethod(Context context) {
        this.mLocale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
    }

    public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
        return source != null ? source.toString().toLowerCase(this.mLocale) : null;
    }

    public void onFocusChanged(View view, CharSequence sourceText, boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
    }
}
```

Then, you can use this:

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        nameTextview.setTransformation(new AllLowTransformationMethod); 
    }
});
```

To recover the original text:

```
nameTextview.setTransformation(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   button1.setOnClickListener {
   tvId.setText(tvId.text.toString().toUpperCase())
   }
   button2.setOnClickListener {
   tvId.setText(tvId.text.toString().toLowerCase())
   }
```